# Can it really be, that a transaction lasts longer than a session in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have simple question about hibernate:

Can it really be, that a transaction lasts longer than a session in hibernate?

```
@Controller
public class VacancyMenuController extends AbstractController{

...
   @RequestMapping("/path")
   public String delete(Model model){
  //here session opens and transaction starts ?
                 vacancyService.delete(vacancy.getId());
 //here transactions commit and session close ?

        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();

 //here session opens and transaction starts    ?
    Vacancy vacancyFromDb = vacancyService.findById(vacancy.getId());
//here transactions commit and session close    ?

        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();


    }
}
```

---

```
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = false)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/test/BeanConfig.xml" })
    public class AbstractServiceTest  extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests{
           ....
           @Test
        public void delete(){
//here session opens and transaction starts 
            vacancyService.delete(vacancy.getId());

            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();

            Vacancy vacancyFromDb = vacancyService.findById(vacancy.getId());   

            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();

            Assert.assertNull(vacancyFromDb);
//here transactions commit and session close
        }
}
```

in code snippets above my comments is right ?

Answer (score 0):

[`Yes, exactly`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Transaction.html)

> It is intended that there be at most one uncommitted Transaction associated with a particular Session at any time

Example:

[From docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html)

```
// BMT idiom
Session sess = factory.openSession();
Transaction tx = null;
try {
    tx = sess.beginTransaction();

    // do some work
    ...

    tx.commit();
}
catch (RuntimeException e) {
    if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
    throw e; // or display error message
}
finally {
    sess.close();
}
```

You can find the Transaction surrounded by a session here.

Comment: I gues that transaction shorter than session at this example. transaction began after session had been opened. and transaction had closed before session closed

Comment: @gstackoverflow  Edited my words. But you completed the work with in the transaction right ?? That means before committing transaction.

Comment: this order: 1.session opens
   2.transaction sarts
   3.transaction commits
  4.session closed

Comment: Yes,True. Thus `most one uncommitted Transaction associated with a particular Session at any time` is satisfied , right ??

Comment: Question was about posibility this order //some actions// after transaction starts //session opens // session close //transactions commit

Comment: Transaction(uncommitted) must be surrounded by a session.Since you are doing actions and not committed ,that is ok. But while committing you need a session.